# can not add a name space to spawn node

Tags: ros, spawn-model, namespace, roslauch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<launch>
    <!--<include file="$(find husky_gazebo)/launch/base.urdf.gazebo.launch"/>-->
     <param name="use_sim_time" value="true" />

    <!-- Send the Husky A200 Robot URDF/XACRO to param server -->
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find husky_description)/urdf/base.urdf.xacro'" />

    <!-- Spawn robot in gazebo -->
    <node name="spawn_husky_model" pkg="gazebo_ros"  type="spawn_model" args="$(optenv ROBOT_INITIAL_POSE) -unpause -urdf -param robot_description -model mobile_base />

    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" ns="husky_ns">
        <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
    </node>




    <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch"/>
    <node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf" ns="husky_ns" >
      <rosparam>
        freq: 10.0
        sensor_timeout: 1.0
        publish_tf: true
        odom_used: true
        vo_used: true
        output_frame: odom
      </rosparam>
    </node>
</launch>
```

I want to add a name space to this node but I cant

```
 <!-- Spawn robot in gazebo -->
    <node name="spawn_husky_model" pkg="gazebo_ros"  type="spawn_model" args="$(optenv ROBOT_INITIAL_POSE) -unpause -urdf -param robot_description -model mobile_base ns="husky_ns" />
```

Why I cant add  ? and how can I add a name space for this node ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193310/can-not-add-a-name-space-to-spawn-node/) by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2014-09-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solve it. For `pkg = gazebo` in the argument we add `-gazebo_namespace` while in `pkg=gazebo_ros` we write `-robot_namespace` as follows:

```
<node name="spawn_husky_model" pkg="gazebo_ros"  type="spawn_model" args="$(optenv ROBOT_INITIAL_POSE) -unpause -urdf -param robot_description -model mobile_base -robot_namespace husky_ns " />
```

---

Originally posted by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) with karma: 275 on 2014-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1